# border-image > Semi transparent png behind contents

Tags: css, border-image

I have a photo gallery that I have created a frame for that has a bit of transparent tape at the top. I want it to look like a polaroid taped to my background.
The tape works perfectly onto the background, but i'd like it to also be in front of the picture. I am using a negative margin on my picture to make it overlap the frame. Unfortunately the picture appears to be in front of my frame.

Thank you in advance code gods of the internet.

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
html, body {
 background: black;
    background-repeat:   repeat;
    background-position: left top; 
   background-image: url("http://moof-it.com/testing/body_bg.jpg"); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.galleryspace{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:15px;
 margin:0px;
}
.galleryframe {
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 border-color: white;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:28px 10px 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-image: url(http://moof-it.com/testing/tapeframe2.png) 28 stretch;
    -o-border-image: url(http://moof-it.com/testing/tapeframe2.png) 28 stretch;
    border-image: url(http://moof-it.com/testing/tapeframe2.png) 28 stretch;
}
.imageingallery {
 display:block;
 background:white;
}
.imageingallery img{
 height:240px;
 margin:-12px -3px -1px -1px;
 padding:0px;
}
.imageingallery a {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:14px;
 font-variant:small-caps;
    color: #C27890; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='galleryspace'>
 <center>
 <div class='galleryframe'>
  <div class='imageingallery'>
   <a href='http://moof-it.com/testing/ALittleSpell.jpg' title='A Little Spell'>
   <img src='http://moof-it.com/testing/ALittleSpell.jpg' alt='A Little Spell' title='A Little Spell'>
   <br>
   A Little Spell
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
  </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're supposed to put the CSS and HTML into a single Code snippet, else they are not going to work correctly.

Comment: This was my first post. I normally find my answer here. I have edited it into a piece of code that will run now. Sorry Maharjus.

Comment: hmmm... looks ok to me?

Comment: No problem, welcome to SO!

Comment: @ProEvilz Take a look at the tape. OP wants it to go over the image, but it's below it because they used border-image to place the tape.

Comment: For me, using Chrome, the tape is above?

Comment: Above the **image** or the **border** of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you not to use `border-image` for this, but rather make the tape a separate image and position it the way you want. Here's an example of what I mean. Note that I don't have access to your tape image separately, so I just made a red block. You can replace that with the image of the tape.

```css
html,
body {
  background: black;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-image: url("http://moof-it.com/testing/body_bg.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.galleryspace {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.galleryframe {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.imageingallery {
  display: block;
  background: white;
}

.imageingallery .image {
  height: 240px;
  margin: -12px -3px -1px -1px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.imageingallery a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #C27890;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.blockOver {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: -40px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
  <div class='galleryspace'>
    <center>
      <div class='galleryframe'>
        <div class='imageingallery'>
          <a href='http://moof-it.com/testing/ALittleSpell.jpg' title='A Little Spell'>
            <img class="blockOver" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff0000">
            <img class="image" src='http://moof-it.com/testing/ALittleSpell.jpg' alt='A Little Spell' title='A Little Spell'>
            <br> A Little Spell
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got so blind-sided by the border-image I did not even think about this.